# My master branch is late compared to origin one: what can I do?

Tags: git

On our project, I was working on a `core-update` branch. A colleague, certainly impatient to read my doc and test the update of dependencies on our solution triggered a pull request and immediately merged it using Visual Studio Tools.

Now, there is my git status/history/state:

[image]

The fact is: if I do a `git pull`, it will create a merge commit I guess. **How to simply "get the changes" and move my master head to fit the origin/master one?** I'm quite new in Git and don't want to create a useless merge commit to merge inside Master a remote master.

Comment: Just do a FF merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git pull` will do what you need (assuming your current branch is `master`).

It doesn't have any reason to create a merge commit in your situation. A merge commit is created when the two branches being merged have diverged. Your local `master` branch is 3 commits behind `origin/master` but it is not ahead of it.

Everything you have on `master` already exists on `origin/master`; that's why `git pull` (or `git merge origin/master`) will fast-forward your `master` branch to the commit pointed by `origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks it's clearer now. I didn't know git would do a FF.

Comment: `git fetch` followed by `git status` can give you an insight of what `git pull` will do (`git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch; git merge`). It tells you when a "fast-forward" is possible. A "fast-forward" is a special kind of merge that doesn't create a new commit because it is not needed. Fast-forwarding is possible when the local branch is an ancestor of the remote branch (the remote branch changed but the local branch didn't change since the last time they were in sync). A fast forward basically moves the local branch to the same commit as the remote branch.

Comment: Ok so in my example, I had everything on my local repository. remote only "merged" the branch but nothing more was added. So my local is able to do the same by just getting the merge commit made from PR and then moving the head?

Comment: In the image you posted I can see your local branch is `master`, on the commit "chore: update Dockerfile". The remote repository contains two new commits ("chore: update to ASP Core 1.1" and "doc: add Docker instructions"). They were created on a new branch ("core-update") that you also have on the local repo. Then "core-update" was merged into "master" on the remote repo. A merge commit updates only one branch (the one you merge into). Your local branch "master" is now 3 commits behind (the merge commit and the two pink commits are not in local "master").

Comment: You did `git fetch` (or the GUI program did it for you) and this way you know where `origin/master` is. All the commits displayed in the image are already on your computer (this means you can do `git merge origin/master` even if you are offline) but they are not in the local "master" branch; only the pink commits are in the local "core-update" branch. `git merge origin/master` does not create a new commit because, apart from the commit message, a new merge commit is identical to commit "Merged PR2".

Comment: Thanks for deep explaination :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a `git merge origin/master` while being on your `master` branch.

That'll do a fast-forward merge and update your master branch pointer to the commit at which `origin/master` is pointing.

FF merges:

[Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

> Because the commit C4 pointed to by the branch hotfix you merged in
>   was directly ahead of the commit C2 you’re on, Git simply moves the
>   pointer forward. To phrase that another way, when you try to merge one
>   commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first
>   commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward
>   because there is no divergent work to merge together – this is called
>   a “fast-forward.”

Answer (score 2):

If you're on `master`, simply do:

```
$ git merge origin/master
```

In this case it will fast-forward the `master` branch, because it is a direct ancestor of `origin/master`.

If you want to prevent accidentally creating a merge commit in case `master` has diverged from  `origin/master`, you can use the [`--ff-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---ff-only) option:

```
$ git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

```
--ff
When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer,
without creating a merge commit. This is the default behavior.
```

So by default (unless your git config sets different defaults), there will not be a merge commit, running `git pull`.